# Attaching TextView to ImageView no matter the size of the image

Tags: android, xml, textview, imageview

I have a popup window that consist of a linear layout with a imageview, textview, and button nested with in it. Now, the purpose of this is so when I click on an image in my gallery, the popup window will display the image, text that talks about the image and a button to close the window (that part is not set yet). now the problem is in order to get the elements to display on the screen i had to use weights. So when i click on in image that may not fill the size of the imageview height wise, it leaves huge gap between the imageview and the text, if a picture is more wider, it leave a huge gap between the pictures and the text, as seen in the pics below. How can i get the text to always be xxx dp away from the image regardless of the dimensions of the image?

ps i am using picasso to resize and scale my images

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_borders"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background_container"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />


        <TextView
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/background_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="this is a sample of this files information"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/background_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="Close"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
```

This picture shows the huge gap between the image and the white textview 
[image]
this picture shows the narrow gab between the image and the white textview 
[image]

Comment: if you want to attach a TextView to a ImageView , I think You Should Use a Cardview

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RelativeLayout` and place `textview` below `imageview`. Add `top margin` to `textview` with specific xxx dp so that textview will always appear below imageview leaving space of xxx dp.

Comment: so i set it like such

linearlayout 
-imageview
-realitvieview
--textview
--button

i put the layout_alignParentBottom on the buttonto set it to the bottom
i put the button to be on bottom on textview
i put the whole realtive layout to be attached to imageview, but no luck

Comment: Put `ImageView` and `TextvVew` inside RelativeLayout and add top margin. You can even  remove LinearLayout and just use RelativeLayout if that's ok with your design.

Comment: I did as so with no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use image scaletype to  centercrop, thn your image fit on the imageview without streteching. Hope it may be help you but i am sure your white space is removed

```
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Hope it may be help you

Comment: I just tried it and just broke my picture formatting =/